# Programs run at boot time: where are they hidden?

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, fedora-13

I am struggling to understand where PackageKit is launched from at boot time (fedora FC13), and I'm starting to suspect that - since my previous experiences with much older Linux distros - in modern systems daemons/services/programs are launched at boot time from many other different points.
In my case, I can't find an origin point for this program in /etc/rc5.d
Where can I find a list of places to look into?

Answer (score 0):

After [googling](http://www.fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?p=1449203), it might be `yum-updatesd` that you're asking about?

Addressing your other comment.. rather than looking in /etc/rc5.d, using `chkconfig` is probably far easier.

Try

```
chkconfig --list
```

You can then use chkconfig to disable a service, e.g.

```
chkconfig httpd off
```

---

If this isn't a boot-time thing but something when logging in, try looking in Gnome's System > Preferences > Sessions, then look on the startup tab and in the list there.